# In Apache Airflow, is there a way to capture the error of a bash command?

Tags: python, airflow

In Apache Airflow, is it possible to capture the original error message that the failed bash command produced instead of a traceback error produced by Apache Airflow that tells you that the line failed but not exactly why it failed?

Example line in Dag:

```
gsutil_rsync = BashOperator(
        task_id="task1",
        bash_command='gsutil rsync -r s3://bucket/ gs://bucket',
        dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 2):

I writed this solution with python function and `PythonOperator` and set `xcom_push=True` in `PythonOperator`.

```
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 10, 15),
    'email': 'me@airflow.com',
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': 1,
}


def run_bash():
    result = subprocess.run(['ls', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return result.stdout

run_bash()

with DAG('bash_dag', schedule_interval="@daily", default_args=default_args) as dag:
    start_brach = DummyOperator(task_id='start')

    gsutil_rsync_py = PythonOperator(
        task_id="task1",
        python_callable=run_bash,
        xcom_push=True,
        dag=dag)


    start_brach.set_downstream(gsutil_rsync_py)
```

And result this;

[image]